# How do I catch read/writes to the hard disk and display them on OS X?

Tags: macos, disk, read-write

I'm looking to display read/write attempts by a specific applications, for example when an application attempts to read or write to a file. Is there an application to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I've found how to do this — using Instruments.app (inside of Xcode). You're able to display filesystem operations, which is what I was intending to do.